# iron: What is the default fastrtps version in ros2 iron? Where can I get it?

Tags: ros2

Is there any place where I can know the default fastrtps version number of iron in ros2?

I try searching in /opt/ros/iron/share/fastrtps, but got nothing...

Do you need to manually install the specified version to get the latest version of fast?